# How to set up first differences model?

Tags: r

I am new to R and only know the very basics. Currently I am trying to estimate a model which is very simple, but I have problems thinking about how to set it up. Precisely, I am trying to estimate the following equation:

```
a(t) - a(t-1) = alpha + beta1 c(t) + beta2 c(t+1)
```

My data consists of 341 scenarios and each scenario calculates me 10 values for `a` and 10 values for `c`, meaning I got 10 `t`s, which gives me in total 341x2x10 = 6820 data points.
My problem is that I don't know how to set this up. I brought my data already into tidy format and now I just want to get started, but how?

- Looping approach

  Should I try to estimate this equation for 1 scenario and then try to loop the resulting code over the other scenarios? And if yes, how exactly would I do so? By using the `diff()` function, storing the result somewhere, looping over the other 340 scenarios, which would give me 341 stored results? How would I then combine these 341 results in the end?
- Time series / panel data approach

  Should I rather focus on "the panel data character" of my data? (to be honest I am not even sure if it's panel data or time series). In that case I would read a bit more into working with time series / panel data.

I am sure there are several options to do this (quite basic) estimation. I just don't know which way to go, and once I decide for a specific way, how to carry it out and set it up.
I would just like to have a kind of roadmap for how to set this whole thing up.

Comment: Perhaps an [ARIMA model with differencing and exogenous covariates](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/arimreg.htm) might be a good starting point? In any case, this question seems to be a better fit for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (which deals with more conceptual statistics questions). Stack Overflow is for *specific* coding questions.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I'm not sure about that. OP seems to me to understand the statistics, but doesn't know how to realize the model, i.e. how to code it in R. This again seems to be a case that does not seem to be on-topic on either side. See [discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/shouldnt-cv-be-a-valid-resource-on-how-to-implement-non-trivial-statistical-mod).